# Convexity of a infinite sum of squared exponential (Gaussian)

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, approximation, gaussian-integral

How can I prove the convexity of the function in $(0,\infty)$ for $a,b,\sigma >0$ ?$$f(x)=(a+bx)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{-k^2x^2/\sigma^2}$$

**PS:** **1.** The function is actually convex but only if there are infinitely many squared exponentials. Hence the proof must be using this fact somewhere.
**2.** Limiting value of the function and its first two derivatives can be proven to be $\infty,-\infty,\infty$ respectively.
**3.** Final aim is to minimize the function. So if not convexity, proof of its decreasing nature from $x=0^+$ to the minima will suffice.
(That is, convexity, quasi-convexity or even a proof of single minima would suffice)

Comment: Possible connection with function $\vartheta_3$: see [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiTripleProduct.html).

Comment: @Jean Marie
I was checking this connection and was using this in most of the tried methods. But since there is no simpler form of the Jacobi theta function, it did not result in any solution, at least for me.

Comment: Have tried log-convexity ?

Comment: Had not. But just checked. Firstly due to the sum, that might get more complex. Secondly, we will have to use the $\infty$ somewhere to get to the proof. :(

Comment: Another track: the connection with solutions to the **heat equation**. See for example [here](https://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/~novozhil/Teaching/483%20Data/12.pdf)